# SQL - Your query does not include specified expression in aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to pull a list of customers who have been invoiced in a current period and aggregate the results by company code and showing the summarized customer balance. The error shows "CUS_CODE" as not in the aggregate function but I have it listed in my where and group by so I'm not sure where I've gone astray.

Below is what I have so far:

```
SELECT INVOICE.CUS_CODE, CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, CUS_BALANCE    
FROM INVOICE, CUSTOMER    
WHERE INVOICE.CUS_CODE=CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE    
GROUP BY INVOICE.CUS_CODE, CUS_BALANCE;
```

Comment: Instead: `SELECT INVOICE.CUS_CODE, CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE, SUM(CUS_BALANCE) as SUM_BALANCE FROM INVOICE INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON INVOICE.CU_CODE = CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE GROUP BY INVOICE.CUS_CODE, CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE` When you introduce a `GROUP BY` clause then EVERY column in your `SELECT` clause must either be aggregated with an aggregate function, `SUM()` is used here, or be present in the GROUP BY. Since you have `CUS_CODE` from both tables in your `SELECT` clause, both must also be in your `GROUP BY`. And because we are using `SUM()` on `CUS_BALANCE` then it can't be in your `GROUP BY`.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks so much @JNevill!